# Reflective DLL injected code crashing on ofstream.open()

Tags: dll, reverse-engineering, dll-injection

I am trying to load a library via reflective DLL injection, but it crashes on calling ofstream.open(); calling fopen() yields the same result.

For reflective dll injection i basically follow the steps described at https://0x00sec.org/t/reflective-dll-injection/3080:

1. Load the dll contents in a buffer
2. Create a file mapping and map view of file, then copying the NT headers and sections there.
3. Copy the contents of the mapping to a buffer and close the mapping.
4. Rebuild the import table.
5. Rebuild relocations.
6. Allocate memory in a target suspended process and copy the buffer there.
7. CreateRemoteThread to start the dllMain (while the target process is still suspended).

The code gets loaded and the dllmain is executed.

My dllmain looks like this:

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    logFile.open("hookLog.txt", std::ios::out);
    logFile << "DLL Attached\n";
    HRESULT nResult = InitCoCreateInstanceHook();
    logFile << "Hook initialized with result: " << std::to_string(nResult) << "\n";
    logFile.flush();
}
```

And it crashes while opening the log file. I know exeption handling is not set up when I execute the code, could that be the issue? Am I missing something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to call [_DllMainCRTStartup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/run-time-library-behavior?view=msvc-160) which initializes standard liibrary prior the call to DllMain. You are trying to bypass that initialization by calling DllMain directly. Or you can probably use pure WinAPI which does not require such initialiization.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I am technically calling execution on the entry point of the dll as declared in the PE file. Shouldn't _DllMainCrtStartup be called in this case?

Comment: _DllMainCrtStartup **is** the entry point of the dll so standard library initialization routines are getting called if you invoke it. If you still have issues then you probably need to map some sections of your dll with different attributes: RO , RW, EXEC Only. Probably section of global variables which needs modification is mapped into process for readonly so initialization is not done properly (although I would expect page write exception in this case)

Comment: The injected memory region is allocated with PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, maybe i should still change that, but what I am getting is an access violation.